# Cannot download photos from iCloud via Photos framework for some accounts

Tags: ios, icloud, photosframework

All the time getting an error for the one the same iCloud account when trying download photos from iCloud as photos are not presented on device. The error occurs for all iCloud photos:

> Error Domain=CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=25 "Failed to download CPLResourceTypeOriginal for ARUQNQfwZKmf/HcerGPjcRjjf1/H#PrimarySync (Record not found)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to download CPLResourceTypeOriginal for ARUQNQfwZKmf/HcerGPjcRjjf1/H#PrimarySync (Record not found)}

iOS Settings -> Photos has iCloud Photos enabled. Also in iCloud settings the iCloud is on for Photos app.

Other iCloud accounts work ok. The code for iOS 13

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.version = .original
options.isSynchronous = false
options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
let id = PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: asset, options: options) { data, _, _, info in { /*...*/ }
```